# Views dependency in Redshift

Tags: view, dependencies, amazon-redshift, sql-view

I've got a scenario where my team has built views which relies on other views.

Problem arises when I try to drop and rebuild a view. It removes all the dependent views (drop cascade).

Is there a way to identify views relaying on other views dependency in Redshift?

I know there is a STV_MV_DEPS table to view materialized view dependency but I'm interested in understanding which views relies on which views.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

awslabs has a good git repo of utilities that come in handy at times like this.  https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils

The util you want is likely - https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_view_dependency.sql

If you don't want this util as a view you can just run the SELECT this view use standalone.

Comment: As always, thank you very much for your help @Bill Weiner

Comment: I could be wrong, but that view looks useless - I've just run my eye over it, and I think what you get is one row per link in every dependency chain.  It's impenetrable.

Comment: Is there a better way to solving this @Max?

Comment: Yes, although my answer is self-serving!  in a day or two I'm going to release an AMI, which is a PII and regulatory safe Redshift management web-app.  Amongst other things, it shows dependencies as graphs.